# how to print out each class's Average Precision using Mxnet Faster RCNN for object detection

Tags: computer-vision, deep-learning, object-detection, mxnet

I am using faster rcnn(mxnet) for object detection on my own dataset, which has 9 classes(including background). However, i found that in the end it only prints out the average accuracy over all 9 classes during trainning process. Furthermore, during test process, it also only prints out the average precision and recall over all 9 classes. I am wondering how can i print out each class's accuracy during the training process, and each class's recall and precision during the test process?
Or can someone tell me where should i look at to approach my goal?
An ideal example will be shown in the image. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6Tsr.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Scikit-learn function `sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_fscore_support¶` for this. And `sklearn.metrics.classification_report` for a prettified version.

At test time, you will have an array of true values (`Y_true`) and an array of predicted probabilities for each class (`Y_prob`). Use these as follows;

```
Y_pred = np.argmax(Y_prob, axis=1)
print(classification_report(Y_true, Y_pred))

         precision    recall  f1-score   support
class 0       0.50      1.00      0.67         1
class 1       0.00      0.00      0.00         1
class 2       1.00      0.67      0.80         3
avg / total   0.70      0.60      0.61         5
```

Slightly more work is required for these to be listed every N batches at training time. You can set a callback argument, and a custom `eval_metric` if you're using `module.fit` method;

```
model = mx.mod.Module(symbol=...)
model.fit(..., batch_end_callback = mx.callback.Speedometer(batch_size),
          eval_metric=custom_metric, ...)
```

You'll need to create a new class for `custom_metric` that extends `mxnet.metric.EvalMetric` and implements a `get` method that prints out (or even returns) the per class metrics.